# Script to display a picture burst on Windows

Tags: windows, image, batch-file, streaming, png

I have a Windows command that gets a png picture. I need to create a script that executes it and displays the last picture obtained, giving a live video effect. My main problem is that I don't know how to display the picture burst.

Moreover, as it is going to be used for some kind of video streaming, every past picture will be deleted. I'll have to use this script in a web page with a "start/stop" button to start/stop the streaming.

Would you recommend me using a Windows bat script or any other scripting language? How can I display the picture burst?

Answer (score 0):

You can run an `.HTA` file and put whatever functionality you want:

```
<HTA:Application
    Caption = No
   ShowInTaskbar = No
   BorderStyle=Static

   SysMenu=No
   WindowsState=Maximize
   Border=Thin
   MaximizeButton=No
   MinimizeButton= No
>


<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
<html>
<body>

<img  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/402px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg" width="277" height="413">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.visible=true;
    window.resizeTo(320,480);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```